# Undocumented MakePri.exe

Tags: wpf, packaging

I am trying to app into the store. Since it's a **`WPF`** app I have to use makepri.exe. It keeps failing even though I am following the exact parameters given in the guide. The parameters I am giving it are:

```
cd "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MyCompany.MyApp\MyCompany.MyApp"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\makepri.exe" createconfig /o /cf priconfig.xml /dq en

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\makepri.exe" new /o /v /pr . /cf priconfig.xml
```

It creates the **`priconfig.xml`** from the second line but fails on the 3rd line.

```
Option Verbose specified
Option ProjectRoot specified
Option Configxml specified
MakePri: warning: Output location of PRI file(s) is detected to be under the project root. If previously generated PRI file(s) is present, these may be re-indexed and lead to unexpected results.
Index Pass Completed.
AlternateForm Qualifiers: UNPLATED
Language Qualifiers: en,de,es,fr,ja
Scale Qualifiers: 100,400,150,125,200,150,125,400,100
TargetSize Qualifiers: 256,16,24,32,48


MakePri: error 0x80073b0d: Processing Resources failed with error: Invalid ResourceCandidate type.

MakePRI: error 0xdef01023: Unspecified error occurred.
```

I thought it was because I had **`Resources.zh.resx`** but it still happens after I removed the file from the project. Does anyone have any advice on how I can make it work? not sure why it's listing the scale qualifiers twice now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working by setting the platform version (still undocumented)

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\makepri.exe" createconfig /o /cf priconfig.xml /pv 10.0.0 /dq en

Once that was set the third command worked.